# Why is my GLSL transformation not rendering?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

So I'm learning OpenGL and GLSL (obviously). I've followed several tutorials religiously on matrix transformations, but I can't figure out why the square isn't rendering. I've figured out through trial and error that my rendering code is fine, it's just when I do "transformation * vec4(...)" in the vertex shader that the program messes up. I checked the returned value of glGetUniformLocation and I got a return value of 0, so it's getting the location of the uniform. I've looked around and I haven't found a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

const GLchar* VertShaderCode = "\
#version 330 core\n\
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;\n\
uniform mat4 transformation;\n\
void main ()\n\
{\n\
    vec4 lol = transformation * vec4(position.xy, 0, 1);\n\
    gl_Position = lol;\n\
}\n\
";

const GLchar* FragShaderCode = "\
#version 330 core\n\
void main ()\n\
{\n\
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);\n\
}\n\
";

#define SDL_main main

#define scuffed !SDL_QuitRequested()

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING))
    {
        printf("Could not initialize SDL!\n");
        return -4;
    };

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Testing Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 420, 420, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!window)
    {
        printf("Could not create window!\n");
        return -5;
    };

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (!context)
    {
        printf("Could not create context!\n");
        return -7;
    };

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("Could not initialize GLEW!\n");
        return -6;
    };

    GLint err;
    char* log = NULL;

    //printf("Vertex Shader Source: \n%s\n",VertShaderCode);
    GLuint VertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VertShader,1,&VertShaderCode,NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertShader);
    glGetShaderiv(VertShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&err);
    if (err == GL_FALSE)
    {
        // Shader didn't compile.
        glGetShaderiv(VertShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &err);
        log = (char*)malloc(err);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertShader,err,NULL,log);
        printf("Vertex shader could not be compiled!\n\n%s\n\n",log);
        return -1;
    };

    //printf("Fragment Shader Source: \n%s\n", FragShaderCode);
    GLuint FragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(FragShader, 1, &FragShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragShader);
    glGetShaderiv(FragShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &err);
    if (err == GL_FALSE)
    {
        // Shader didn't compile.
        glGetShaderiv(FragShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &err);
        log = (char*)malloc(err);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragShader, err, NULL, log);
        printf("Fragment shader could not be compiled!\n\n%s\n\n", log);
        return -2;
    };

    GLuint Program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(Program,VertShader);
    glAttachShader(Program,FragShader);
    glLinkProgram(Program);
    glGetProgramiv(Program,GL_LINK_STATUS,&err);
    if (err == GL_FALSE)
    {
        // Program didn't link.
        glGetProgramiv(Program,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&err);
        log = (char*)malloc(err);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(Program,err,NULL,log);
        printf("Program could not be linked!\n\n%s\n\n",log);
        return -3;
    };

    glUseProgram(Program);

    GLuint vertBuff = 0, arrayBuff = 0, elementBuff = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &arrayBuff);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertBuff);
    glGenBuffers(1, &elementBuff);
    glBindVertexArray(arrayBuff);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuff);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuff);

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5,  0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5,
         0.5, -0.5,

         0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5,  0.5,
         0.5,  0.5,
    };
    GLubyte colors[] =
    {
        255,0,0,
        0,255,0,
        0,0,255
    };

    GLuint indicies[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 0, 3,
    };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glm::mat4 mat = glm::scale(mat, glm::vec3(2, .5, 0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(Program, "transformation"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mat));

    while (scuffed)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &arrayBuff);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertBuff);
    //glDeleteBuffers(1, &elementBuff);

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the code in the shader, but the data you pass to `transformation`:

```
glm::mat4 mat = glm::scale(mat, glm::vec3(2, .5, 0));
```

The `glm::scale function` multiplies a new scaling function to the `mat` you pass in. The problem is, that `mat` is not initialized when you pass it to `scale` and contains just some random garbage. What you actually want is to initialize the matrix first (as an identity matrix, but that's the default behavior), and then pass it to scale:

```
glm::mat4 mat;
mat = glm::scale(mat, glm::vec3(2, .5, 0));
```

Note, that these two version are not equivalent in c++ since the first version doesn't call the constructor of `mat` before passing it to the function.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and this seemed to work. I went back to look at the tutorials and it said to do exactly that when others didn't. Guess some people don't check to see if their code works and aren't as good as they claim to be. Thanks!